# R: parallel importing data from SQL Server does not return data

Tags: r, sql-server, parallel-processing

I have to import 8 years of monthly data, where each month contains cca. 360.000 observations, and each has 75 variables. Data are stored in SQL Server.

I tried importing it year by year by this code, but final dataframe is not created. Additionally, `r` shoud condatin all years, but each value is the same.

This is my code:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

numCores <- detectCores()

system.time({
  nr_years <- 8
  start_year <-  2010
  registerDoParallel(numCores)

  steps <- foreach::foreach(icount(nr_years), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    next_year <- start_year +1 
    date_before <- paste0(start_year, '-12-31', sep = '')
    date_end <- paste0(next_year, '-12-31', sep = '')

    myQuery <- RxSqlServerData(sqlQuery = sprintf("SELECT DATE,CLIENT_NO,MAT_ST
                           FROM DBO.DATA_TABLE 
                           WHERE DATE >='%s' and DATE <= '%s'", date_before, date_end), connectionString = connStr, returnDataFrame = TRUE)
    
    my_df <- rxImport(myQuery)
    #start_year <- start_year + 1 
    
  }
})
```

I tested code by replacing `%dopar%` with `%do%`: dataframes were not combined, but rewritten (object `steps` was correct).

However, I want data to be imported parallely and at the end all years should be binded in dataframe `my_df`.

### **Note**

I've found out that in case of `%dopar%` the results of the last line of `foreach` function are saved to `steps` (so I've commented the last line). However, data are still not `rbinded` but only contain results from first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In parallel processing partial results are made and are "saved" to different objects and saved only when merged at the end. So the problem was saving data to objects.

I've found a solution that works for lower number of variables

```
period <- function(it){
  res <- c(paste0(start_year + it, '-12-31', sep = ''), paste0(start_year + 1 + it, '-12-31', sep = ''))

}

system.time({
  numCores <- detectCores()
  start_year <-  2016
  registerDoParallel(numCores)

  raz2 <- foreach(i=0:3, .combine = rbind, .multicombine = TRUE) %dopar% {
    dates <- period(i)
    myQuery <- RxSqlServerData(sqlQuery = sprintf("SELECT DATE,CLIENT_NO,MAT_ST
                           FROM DBO.DATA_TABLE 
                           WHERE DATE >='%s' and DATE <= '%s'", dates[[1]], dates[[2]]), connectionString = connStr, returnDataFrame = FALSE)
    rxImport(myQuery)
  }
})
```

However, if I want to import 75 variables, I get error:

> Error in { : task 2 failed - "bad allocation" Timing stopped at: 34.97
>   7.33 392.9